# Poisson regression predictions

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I've started looking at GLMs and I've worked out point estimates for Poisson regression using the canonical exponential link function. So the likelihood being

$$ \ell(y_i \vert x_i, \beta) = \sum_{i=1}^N \big [ y_i\beta^Tx_i - \exp(\beta^Tx_i) - \log \Gamma (x_i + 1) \big ] $$

and the gradient being

$$ \frac{\partial\ell}{\partial \beta} = \sum_{i=1}^N \big [ y_i - \exp(\beta^Tx_i) \big] x_i $$

I generated some data using the following process

```
xs = np.random.uniform(low, high, size=100)
means = intercept + slope * xs
ys = np.array([stats.poisson(mu).rvs() for mu in means])
```

and plotting that on a graph gives the following

[image]

Very straightforward so far. So the further left we move on the $x$ axis, the larger the variance.

However, when do maximum likelihood estimation using the previously derived gradients, I get the following picture.

[image]

The blue dots are the true generated data and the green dots represent the predictions of the model i.e. $\exp(\beta^T x_i)$. It definitely seems to be fitting the data properly, but what threw me off what the exponential curve of the predictions. Given the canonical link function being the exponential, I suppose it makes sense, but it's not really what I expected.

I expected the predictions to follow the straight line, be it a bit shifted up or down to accommodate the sampling noise. Was I wrong to assume this? Is there a way to achieve the model following a straight line? I am aware that in this particular case, Gaussian linear regression would probably do just fine, but that's not my question. Have I generated the data in such a way that the model couldn't fit it?

Code used:

```py
slope = 2
intercept = 10
low, high = 0, 500
boundaries = np.array([low, high])

xs = np.random.uniform(low, high, size=100)
means = intercept + slope * xs
ys = np.array([stats.poisson(mu).rvs() for mu in means])

xs_ = np.vstack((np.ones_like(xs), xs))

def neg_log_likelihood(beta, xs, ys):
    return -np.sum(ys * (beta @ xs) - np.exp(beta @ xs))

def grad(beta, xs, ys):
    return -np.sum((ys - np.exp(beta @ xs)) * xs, axis=1)

beta = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, 2)

beta_prime = optimize.fmin_bfgs(neg_log_likelihood, beta, fprime=grad, args=(xs_, ys))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your axes were labeled so we knew exactly what we were looking at from the graphs alone.

Comment: I mean, sure, but I don't know that "x" and "target" labels are very informative. This is literally just a bit of synthetic data so that I could fit a model.

Comment: Perhaps just $x$ and $exp(β^Tx)$ would do.

Comment: The canonical link function in a Poisson GLM is the *log* link. If the relationships is linear, then it won't make sense to use a non-linear link function, where the $\exp$ in your model post comes from the inverse of the $\log$ link function. In which case, you might look at the identity link function.

Comment: Can we have all your code?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I've added the code I used.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I see. I was under the impression that I know that I have count data, it is more reasonable to do Poisson regression. And even further, assume I have very non-normal noise, like exponential noise, but the means are still determined by a linear releationship. What might be reasonable in that scenario?

Comment: You aren't using the link function when you generate the data, but the model assumes the link function in fitting the data.

Comment: @gung That makes sense, but then my question is, assuming a linear model but with Poisson noise, how would I go about fitting that?

Comment: Note that a "linear model" (more correctly a Poisson GLM with an identity link) would necessarily go out of bounds at some point (you can't have counts <0).  Do you really need to fit this manually?  Plenty of software already exist to do this easily.  There are functions available in R and Python, eg.

Comment: Yes, this was my reasoning exactly for using the $exp(\cdot)$, since $\lambda$ cannot be negative. I don't *need* to fit this manually, it's more of a learning exercise. So what you're saying is that I could use an identity link instead to get what I want, but I'd need to handle negative values somehow? Any tips on how this is usually handled?

Comment: Usually we don't use an identity link ;-). I respect the idea of a learning exercise.  I would just generate the data with a standard log link.

Comment: You need to evaluate goodness-of-fit for a variety of multiplicative, additive, and geometric  mixture models for Poisson regression in order to determine the best fit of the data.    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409124/modeling-opioid-mortality-rates-using-poisson-regression/409340?noredirect=1#comment765891_409340

Comment: @gung That's not very satisfying though :) what about an example where the data still lie on a line, but the noise is exponential, so it can have really far out outliers. Clearly, linear regression won't work well there. What might be a goo thing to do in that case?

Comment: That set-up doesn't sound like a Poisson GLM; there isn't a separate noise term in that model. It sounds more like a heteroscedastic linear model problem, which could be estimated using Generalised least squares, a Gaussian location scale model, quantile regression, or sandwich estimators with a linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments have already pointed out, you didn't fit the same model you used to generate the data.

The glm you used to generate data has
 $E(Y|x) = \beta_0+\beta_1 x$ but the one you
 fitted has $E(Y|x) = \exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)$.

You if you want data from a log-link Poisson you need to change the way you generate the data (exponentiate in the step where you compute means).

If you want to fit an identity-link Poisson (i.e. you want the straight-line relationship between $E(Y|x)$ and $x$), then you must specify an identity-link Poisson model to the glm-fitting function.